# Can't write to file NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I try to write in file using sdk.

```js
var fs = require('sdk/io/fs');

fs.writeFile('text.ini', '123', null, function (error) {
  callback(error);
});
```

But i obtain `NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH`. Which path should I use?

Comment: As your first argument you probably need to give it full path like `'C:\blah\blah\text.ini'`

Comment: but if i want relative profile path?

Comment: Relative to what? I don't think any write functions to realtive paths. But SDK is weird ot it might, try `'/text.ini'` or `'\text.ini'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain special directories' path with `sdk/system`.

```js
const { pathFor } = require('sdk/system')
const path = require('sdk/fs/path'); // important for cross-platform compatibility 

var profile = pathFor('ProfD');
var filepath = path.join(profile, 'text.ini');

// now pass filepath to writeFile
```

Comment: ProfD is persistent directory? Can i access files after browser restart?

Comment: Yes, it is. Yes, you can.